# Problem with menu categories doubling up when updating database?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, database

I imported a database from a website to my localhost and the menu categories started doubling up. The wordpress dashboard is also missing my custom post types. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like the import went bad but it is hard to say much given the information provided.

Comment: Sorry I actually missed some folders in my wamp wordpress folder.Somehow the smartgit pull didn't fill them up. it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin folder had not been pulled by SmartGit. After deleting the wordpress folder on my local host and pulling again from the git it worked.